# How to extend function in gradle to specific projects?

Tags: gradle, gradle-dependencies

There is a question  :
Using "gradle.allprojects" we can make our function to be available from all sub projects :

```
gradle.allprojects {
  ext.checkSomething = {
    id, value ->
      return isNew(id, value)
  }
}
```

How could I extend it just for few specific projects ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below notation will make it apply on sub-project named subA

```
project(':subA') {
}
```

or condition based inside allprojects

```
allprojects {
    if (condition) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like in "project" cannot be indicated more than one subproject like here :

project(':subA', ':subB') {
}

Comment: with conditions worked , thanks!

if( projectsList.contains(project.name)){

}